# Sort array without displaying commas

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm the perfect case of the "most computer savvy guy gets the task."
On the website I'm making, I need to sort a large number of names. The names change often, and lots of people change them. The number of names also change, so indexing by number would also not be a good thing.

My sample code I found looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fruits = ["Banana<br />", "Orange<br />", "Apple<br />", "Mango<br />",];
document.write(fruits.sort());
</script>
```

This works with the exception that the commas are displayed on the website. This isn't acceptable. I'm looking for a way to make the commas go away from the website when it's displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An array isn't a string, and the default way of converting it is to join the elements by `,`. Just specify your own joining string instead:

```
var fruits = ["Banana<br />", "Orange<br />", "Apple<br />", "Mango<br />",];
document.write(fruits.sort().join('')); // Don't join by anything
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method returns the sorted array. You could apply it the [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method to concatenate all elements of this array using a separator before outputting it:

```
document.write(fruits.sort().join(''));​
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the commas are being displayed because you are writing an collection to the document and hence a separator is being displayed.  To avoid this write out the entries manually

```
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  document.write(fruits[i]);
}
```

Note: It's generally better practice to separate data from display.  In this case you mixed the data (fruit name) with the display information (`<br/>`).  Another way to consider writing this is the following

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.sort();
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  document.write(fruits[i]);
  document.write("<br/>");
}
```