# Javascript filter common words out of a string

Tags: javascript, string, pattern-matching

I am trying to filter any common words out of a string. I found this code on the internet, and it looks like it will work perfect but how do I modify it to not return a string with ','?

---

Current code:

```
function getUncommon(cquerySearch, filterCommonWords) {
var wordArr = sentence.match(/\w+/g),
    commonObj = {},
    uncommonArr = [],
    word, i;

common = common.split(',');
for ( i = 0; i < common.length; i++ ) {
    commonObj[ common[i].trim() ] = true;
}

for ( i = 0; i < wordArr.length; i++ ) {
    word = wordArr[i].trim().toLowerCase();
    if ( !commonObj[word] ) {
        uncommonArr.push(word);
    }
}
return uncommonArr;
}
```

---

This returns an array like `uncommonArr = 'Return, String, Would, Go, Here'`. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but can you replace the line `return uncommonArr` with `return uncommonArr.join(' ')`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array without displaying commas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446321/sort-array-without-displaying-commas)? Maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behaviour of `Array.toString` is to join with a `,`. Just specify a custom join string:

```
uncommonArr.join(' '); // Join with a space, for example
```